# Python global variable in open file

Tags: python, file, variables, global

Hi guys I have question about global variable. How can I put filename into varibale and call it on global.
My code:

```
for filename in dirs:
    if filename.startswith("EPG_NatGeo"):
            z = filename


output_file = open('nat.xml','w') 
with open (r'{}','r').format(z) as file:
```

How can varibale became file for opening? Thx for reading this post!

Comment: And what error do you see when you run this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `.format()` at all here:

```
with open(z, 'r') as file:
```

and even if you did, you'd call it on the string object, not the open file:

```
with open('foo_{}_bar'.format(z), 'r') as file:
```

Note that `z` is re-bound in your loop more than once if multiple `filename` values match your `.startswith()` test, you'll only be passing the last match to `open()`. If *no* values match you run the risk of `z` never having been bound at all and you'll get a `NameError` exception instead.

Use `break` to pick the first match, and use `else:` on the `for` loop to detect that no match was made:

```
for filename in dirs:
    if filename.startswith("EPG_NatGeo"):
        z = filename
        break
else:
    raise ValueError('No filename matched')
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn Pieters for answer! You helped me out!